# C# Selenium WebDriver Switch/Case

Tags: c#, selenium, switch-statement, case

```
public enum ElementType
{
    Id,
    ClassName,
    Name,
    XPath,
    CssSelector,
    LinkText
}

public static class WebDriverExtensions
{

    public static void AssertElementDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver, ElementType elementType, string element)
    {
        if (elementType == ElementType.Id)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element)).Displayed);
        if (elementType == ElementType.ClassName)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(element)).Displayed);
        if (elementType == ElementType.Name)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Name(element)).Displayed);
        if (elementType == ElementType.XPath)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(element)).Displayed);
        if (elementType == ElementType.CssSelector)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(element)).Displayed);
        if (elementType == ElementType.LinkText)
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(element)).Displayed);
    }

    public static void WaitForElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, ElementType elementType, string element)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        if (elementType == ElementType.Id)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(element)));
        if (elementType == ElementType.ClassName)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName(element)));
        if (elementType == ElementType.Name)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name(element)));
        if (elementType == ElementType.XPath)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(element)));
        if (elementType == ElementType.CssSelector)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(element)));
        if (elementType == ElementType.LinkText)
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText(element)));
    }
```

I'm looking for the best way to convert this to a switch case statement rather than using if statements but unsure on the best way to achieve this. I need a simple way to switch between By.Id, By Class, By.Name etc...

Comment: Just write a plain switch statement? What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Selenium, but would something like this work?

```
private By GetElement(ElementType type, string element)
{
    switch(ElementType)
    {
        case ElementType.Id:
            return By.Id(element);
        // add your other cases here!
    }
}
```

You could then use that in your methods as follows:

```
public static void WaitForElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, ElementType elementType, string element)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(GetElement(elementType, element)));
}
```

Comment: I bet it was because the OP is doing asserts and you are just returning "by".  *shrugs*  But I agree, downvote needs a required comment on it, as downvoting is not helpful if it's not explained why it was downvoted.

Comment: @IamBatman I proposed a new method that returns just a By, which seems to be exactly what is needed where it is used... If Selenium doesn't accept a generic `By` instead of the subclasses of `By` such as `By.Id` I'd be surprised, but then the switch can be moved to the original methods.

Comment: Yeah, I know, was just assuming that's why it was downvoted.  Any real programmer could of taken what you wrote and figured out what you were doing.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to pass all this extra info. Just pass around a `By` locator and it takes care of the rest and makes the code much simpler.

```
public static void AssertElementDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(locator).Displayed);
}
```

and

```
public static void WaitForElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By locator, int timespan)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timespan)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));
}
```

Comment: Having posted all this, I think this is not the right way to go about this (having a separate method for each). This code should go into your script itself... `Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(...).Displayed);` and so on. There's not much reason to write methods that wrap one-liners.

Comment: The only reason I've put it as an operator is because multiple people will be working on the same Project, some who have less experience than others and can simply use the method.

Comment: That's really not a good reason. It doesn't take any longer to show them the right way to do things vs pointing them to a function that does the same thing. Create a cheat sheet for them or write a doc of best practices, common problems, etc. They will have it to refer to and write better code in the end. Save helper methods for something with some complexity.